# What SOT-23-5 chip is a 90E07 or 4887?

Tags: led, identification, buck

This part is on a buck converter used as an LED driver for outdoor lights. It looks like a 5-pin voltage regulator or comparator with 2 pins on one side and 3 on the other. The markings are:

90E07
4887

I can't find any matches anywhere for it.

Pin 1, lower left, seems to be ground. You can see the minus symbol on the chip cutoff on the left. That is the bridge rectifier. The regulator is labelled U1.

[image].

Additional image
[image]

Comment: Not answer-worthy, but searching "SOT-23-5 90E07" returns some results that include "IC LED" from websites with questionable urls that you may examine if you dare.

Comment: I realized that this is not necessarily a voltage regulator. It could be a comparator or something else. I hope that by trying to draw out the circuit, I can see what might work in that position on the board.

Comment: I don't see any capacitors placed near it which makes me doubt that it's a regulator. My guess is that it's more likely something like an opamp. Definitely try to trace the circuit so see what kind of component might make sense there.

Comment: I included a new view. I can't tell for sure, but a trace disappears under the chip. It looks like a tab that goes under the chip. So it may have 6 connections. Would it be appropriate to edit one more time and also include the schematic I've come up with? This is an obsolete LED driver out of a discontinued floodlight